# set focus to first control on ajax tabpanel in asp.net page using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tabs

I have many tabs in tabcontainer on my asp page. I want to set focus on the first control of the tab on each tab selection. I found that tabpanel has some client events like onclientclick. But that client events are fire on page load. I want to do it in javascript. My page layout has given below.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" Runat="Server"> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtPanel" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server"> 
<ContentTemplate> <asp:TabContainer ID="tabContainerMaster" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="3" UseVerticalStripPlacement="True"> 
<asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="header1" ID="tab1">
..........
```

Is there any way to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing event "OnClientActiveTabChanged" may solve your problem

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="tabContainerMaster" OnClientActiveTabChanged = "clientActiveTabChanged" ...
```

And the JS function can be like this, you want it in Javascript, right?

```
function clientActiveTabChanged(sender, args)
{
   sender.get_tabs()[sender.get_activeTabIndex()].get_element().children[0].focus();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your code. I got the tabpanel object. But children[0] is not getting the first control. I want the first enabled control in the tab.

Comment: hmm, I think I missed get_elemen() method, I have updated my answer, you can try it now

Comment: Thanks @Pawan Nogariya. It worked well. I got div container which contains all my controls. Now can u tell, how can i get first input type like text, dropdown, checkbox, radio button control etc from the particular div element.

Comment: you are welcome! You can find it like this sender.get_tabs()[sender.get_activeTabIndex()].get_element().getElementsByTagName("select") or 
sender.get_tabs([sender.get_activeTabIndex()].get_element().getElementsByTagName("input"), for specific types of input like radio, checkbox etc. you can loop to the returned array of elements and can check there "type" attribute